# how to send http request using localhost in virtual machine of digital ocean?

Tags: node.js, nginx, digital-ocean, pm2, adonis.js

I really try solved this for my part but is imposible!
I Have two node apps (a make in expo and a make in node with adonisJs) i use nginx for render app and i use pm2 for deploy node api ... i try to send http request for my api in localhost virtual machine and always fail

There is a some way for help me? thanks for the answers
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: To be clear. The client doing the request is _running on the same machine_ (virtual or not) than the server? I suspect it is not, in which case you will need to use the ip address where the server is listening (such as the VM ip) in order to connect.

Comment: In this case the client is hosed in the same virtual machine whit the api

Comment: And how does nginx into the mix? The error states clearly that connection to localhost:3000 was rejected, so on the machine that showed that error, there was no server listening at port 3000 at that time...

Comment: I install nginx try to solve the problem.. the client never found the api in the localhost

Comment: your nginx is simply serving contents from port 3000 on port 8080. It won't help at all for communication problems on loclahost!

Comment: You can list the processes listening and on which ports with `netstat -ltp`. Maybe that will give you an idea. But if the screen captures are from the same VM where the server it should be listening, it's simply that the server app is not running. Or if it did, it might have died and that's why now it isn't.

Comment: The client (The frontend) is running in nginx, the virtual machine can mount the node api in other port but the frontend does not can found my localhost..  i try  to call my api of my client running in nginx

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding a subdomain in nginx and adding a port